# TCP DF packets get block though in IPTABLES the required port is allowed by rule

Tags: network-protocols, iptables

The rule is added to accept on Port 10000 as:

iptables -I INPUT 5 -i eth0  -p tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT

But the packet to 10000 port is blocked by ipatables with this log:

packet-droppedIN=eth0 OUT= MAC=<00:00:00:00:aa:59:00:90:30:00:00:00:00:00> SRC=10.78.34.175 DST=10.78.34.171 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=58229 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=50694 DPT=10000 WINDOW=5840 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

Any idea?

Please dont close this question as irrelevant to programming.

Comment: did you try a.n.other application that communicates through this port? i.e. just setup a test client/server app from the internet and make it use this port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Port 10000 is listening on server:

> netstat -an |grep "10000"

Then check your src ip in server firewall as:

> iptables -nL |grep yourIP

if you have installed any other firewall check in that too.

Comment: This was working again properly. May be some other error with setting the configuration